# Design Patterns Key-value data stores application layer

Tags: hazelcast, infinispan, gemfile, key-value-store, ignite

Hello I am trying to find a reading about how to design your application layer when dealing with Key-Value data stores. In my case an In memory data grid.

So far from own experience I have ended with Domain Driven Design. I was wondering if there are any recommendations, or blueprints or design patters that can be followed. Or good books on this topic.

Can you commend a bit over my choice - Domain Driven Design for data grid based programming ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Key-Value provides an abstraction to work with KV storages. [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/keyvalue/docs/current/reference/html/#key-value) provides a brief overview of usage pattern. You can use it as inspiration for designing your application layer.

[Spring-Data-Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast-incubator/spring-data-integrations-commons) project is built on top of SDKV.

Answer (score 1):

In Ignite usually [Data Grid](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-grid) is considered as a data layer an application logic can work with. I would take a look at the main concepts of Data Grid and see how your application logic lays on top of it.